# replacing multiple columns with awk for specific lines

Tags: unix, replace, awk

I want to replace columns 3, 4 and 5 of a.com with 6 , 7 and 8th columns of b.com for specific lines.

```
awk 'NR==FNR{a[NR]=$6;next}FNR>5&&FNR<5287{$3=a[FNR]}1' b.com a.com
```

-will replace columns one at a time. Can I modify this command so that it will replace all the three columns?

Eg:-

a.com:

```
a b 1 2 3 4
c d 3 2 1 4
```

b.com:

```
a d e f k 3 4 5 l
p q w e g 5 4 3 m
```

Desired output:

```
a b 3 4 5 4
c d 5 4 3 4
```

Comment: Could you provide some sample input and output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
awk 'NR==FNR {fld6[NR]=$6; fld7[NR]=$7; fld8[NR]=$8; next}
FNR>5 && FNR<5287 {$3=fld6[FNR]; $4=fld7[FNR]; $5=fld8[FNR]}1' b.com a.com
```

**Logic:**

- Store the columns you need from `b.com` into arrays indexed at line number
- Once that similar line is reached in `a.com`, you replace the columns from `b.com` by referencing the array.
- `FNR>5 && FNR<5287` This is to modify these specific lines. For every line you can remove this

**Test**

```
$ cat a.com 
a b 1 2 3 4
c d 3 2 1 4
```

```
$ cat b.com 
a d e f k 3 4 5 l
p q w e g 5 4 3 m
```

```
$ awk 'NR==FNR {fld6[NR]=$6; fld7[NR]=$7; fld8[NR]=$8; next}
{$3=fld6[FNR]; $4=fld7[FNR]; $5=fld8[FNR]}1' b.com a.com
a b 3 4 5 4
c d 5 4 3 4
```

Answer (score 0):

I would first use [paste](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?paste) and then awk.

```
paste a.com b.com > c.com
```

This command puts a.com and b.com in a new file as adjacent columns.

Then to the awk part,

```
awk '{print $3,$4,$5,$10,$11,$12}' c.com
```

(You'll have to clean it up depending on how many columns were actually in a.com

As one command

```
paste a.com b.com | awk '{print $3,$4,$5,$10,$11,$12}'
```

**edit:** maybe this doesn't work if OP needs only specific rows (lines)